# Entity Framework Context is quite slow, not sure because of my coding or generally slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I found EF is quite slow to start. And wanted to know, because of my coding design or generally EF is slow.

I have got few tables

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<ClientModel> ClientModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeeModel> EmployeeModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClientContactModel> ClientContactModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FileModel> FileModels { get; set; }
    ........
}
```

And I am using IRepository for each model. For examoke Client Model

```
 public interface IClientRepository
{
    IQueryable<ClientModel> ClientModel { get; }
    bool SaveClient(ClientViewModel client);
    bool DeleteClient(int? clientID);
}

 public class ClientRepository : IClientRepository
{
 constructor ...
 public IQueryable<ClientModel> ClientModel => context.ClientModels.OrderBy(c => c.ClientName);
}
```

**In my Startup**  for each model

```
  services.AddTransient<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>();
```

And Finally  my Controller i can access the data

```
private IClientRepository clientRepository;
private IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

public ClientController(IClientRepository _clientRepository, IEmployeeRepository _emp)
    {
        clientRepository = _clientRepository;
        employeeRepository = _emp;
    }
```

Is it the best way to get the data from database or shall i use context without interfaces- something like this

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
public ClientController(ApplicationDbContext cont)
    {
        context = cont;
    }
```

**START UP**

```
 public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) => Configuration = configuration;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString1"]));
        services.AddDbContext<AppIdentityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString2"]));
        services.AddDbContext<AppEmployeeDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString3"]));

        services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppIdentityDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        services.AddTransient<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IEmployeeRepository, EmployeeRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IClientContactRepository, ClientContactRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IFileRepository, FileRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IDolsMcaClientRepository, DolsMcaClientRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IDolsMcaItemRepository, DolsMcaItemRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IMcaRepository, McaRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IIncidentRepository, IncidentRepository>();



        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000 * 60 * 60); //1hr
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStatusCodePages();
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseAuthentication();


        app.UseMvc(routes => {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Empty!");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you observing that you define as "slow"?

Comment: When i click Start Debugging, it takes a minute to start the first page.

Comment: it will take some time for the first time.

Comment: That's pretty normal and it doesn't usually have anything to do with Entity Framework. Why do you believe that EF is holding it up?

Comment: I used Dapper, for this project in the beginning and it is quite fast and better. But couldn't figure out how to use identity with dapper so changed this web to EF now but it is quite slow to start. Any updates or change i am wasting times.

Comment: is it .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: it is .NET CORE

Comment: Can you share your whole startup and dbcontext classes? You may be running migrations every time your project starts.

Comment: _When i click Start Debugging, it takes a minute to start the first page._ what makes you think that has anything to do with the context class?

Answer (score 1):

> I found EF is quite slow to start. And wanted to know, because of my
>   coding design or generally EF is slow.

1. First of all, if you are using Entity Framework Core you don't need to create extra Repository layer as EF Core is a repository by itself. Instead of creating extra `Repository` classes and `IRepository` interfaces you can create extension methods for your entities and inject the `ApplicationDbContext` directly to your services. You can have a look at what is the idea of this approach [here](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/#option-2-ddd-styled-entity-classes)
2. When you know that you only read the data in the given scope you can use lazy loading to improve the speed of your queries. This can give you a big performance boost. Check also how [AsNoTracking](http://www.krisvandermast.com/post/2018/02/03/Use-AsNoTracking-to-speed-up-Entity-Framework-performance.html) thingy works to improve the performance
3. Avoid things like this `context.ClientModels.OrderBy(c => c.ClientName);` as it results in `select * from ...` which is quite common problem. I know that in your case you are using the `IQueryable` so you can add some more logic to the query, however, creating an extra field to just only invoke the `OrderBy` on seems like a triumph of form over content.
4. Use `Async` methods as EF Core allows you to do this.
5. If you are saying that Entity Framework is slow maybe think more about the system architecture as in the case where you have to deal with millions of records in your DB you can think about changing approach and denormalized your DB to avoid complex `JOIN` queries as it always has a big impact on the performance when dealing with big data.